# Comparing two columns in two different tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables `A` and `B` where table `A` has a column `X`, table `B` has column `Y`. These columns contain account number information. I want to check whether the account number information in column `A.X` is present in `B.Y`.

Note: Both column `X` and `Y` can have duplicates because these are like  composite primary keys.

How can I do solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you account information in table `A` that is also present in table `B`. The check is done by a correlated subquery that checks for each row in `A` whether the account information is present in `B`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    X
FROM
    A
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            B
        WHERE
            B.Y=A.X
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `INNER JOIN`, like this:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM table1 a 
 INNER JOIN table2 b 
 ON a.X = b.Y
```

**OR**

you can go for `IF EXISTS`,like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a
WHERE EXISTS(
              SELECT 1
              FROM table2 b
              WHERE a.x=b.Y )
```

Answer (score 0):

select distinct(X)
from A,B
WHERE A.X=B.Y

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of account numbers in A that are not in B:

```
SELECT X FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT X FROM A
) A
LEFT JOIN B ON Y = X
WHERE Y IS NULL
```